# Eclipse/Maven/TortoiseSVN Automated updates

Tags: eclipse, maven, svn, tortoisesvn

I'm tired of doing the same things over and over.

How can I make something that:

1. SVN Updates my directory
2. Maven Updates in Eclipse
3. Maven install in Eclipse
4. Maven clean in Eclipse
5. Refresh projects in Eclipse

I have to do this process like 3 to 4 times a day. 
Let's let computers do what they do best: repetitive mundane tasks.

Any suggestions?